# Is there some sort of convenient solution to avoid explicit NSNumber to int conversion?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsnumber

I am using core data, so all my numbers are NSNumbers (since it's an old model I did not use scalar automatic conversion which seems to be available for the new core data).

So my code is full with these conversion statements:

```
[myNSNumberFromCoreDataObject intValue]   which is pretty annoying...
```

**Is there any convenient solution for this or am I trapped now, since I could not use scalar core data modelling?**

Edit:
Ideally one could write some sort of preprocessor statement that checks these cases and automatically just substitutes this automatically - is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always declare the properties on your managed objects as scalars and handle the conversion in getters/setters. Example:

**Header**

```
@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSUInteger count;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
@interface MyEntity ()

@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSNumber* dbCount;

@end

@implementation MyEntity

@dynamic dbCount;

- (void)setCount:(NSUInteger)count {
    self.dbCount = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:count];
}

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return [self.dbCount unsignedIntegerValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestion, while I am in the mids of my project and the core data has been defined without scalar option. I am not exactly sure - are you suggesting to create a setter/getter like this for every of my NSNumber attributes for each entitiy?

Comment: Yes. The conversion for every attribute has to be somewhere and hiding it into managed object implementations seems logical. If you have a lot of attributes, you can probably simplify the code by using X-macros or similar preprocessing technique.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a category method on your NSManagedObject subclass which returns an int, e.g.

```
- (int)myNumberInt
{
    return [self.myNumber intValue];
}
```